# How to format symbolic equations

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Please consider this script:

```
clear variables
clc

syms a1 x1 t th(t) p(t)

x1 = a1*sin(th);
x2 = a2*sin(p) + x1;
```

Running the above script yields:

```
>> x2(t) = a2*sin(p(t)) + a1*sin(th(t))
```

The second term is actually `x1`.

**My question:** is is there any way to let MATLAB recognize `x1` and print out `x2` as:

```
>> x2(t) = a2*sin(p(t)) + x1
```

No hope found with `pretty()` and `simplify()`. Thank you in advanced.

---

**Edit**: to be clear, `x1` must be calculated before `x2`, and ordering the definitions cannot be changed to suit all the dependencies in my actual code.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you assign a value to a variable from another variable, it checks what is present at that particular address, picks it and stores it in the new variable after doing some manipulations if any. Once a value is assigned to the new variable, it has no link with the other variable.

---

In your case, one of the things that can be done is to assign `x2` its value first. i.e.

```
syms a1 a2 x1 t th(t) p(t)
x2 = x1 + a2*sin(p);
x1 = a1*sin(th);
```

**Results:**

```
>> x1

x1(t) =

a1*sin(th(t))
```

```
>> x2

x2(t) =

x1 + a2*sin(p(t))
```

---

Now if you want to display `x2` with the content of `x1`, you can use [**`subs`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) i.e.

```
>> subs(x2, 'x1', x1)

ans(t) =

a2*sin(p(t)) + a1*sin(th(t))
```

So the reverse is also possible.

**Edit:**

Another possibility if you want to assign the variables in the same sequence then you can convert the symbolic expression to char or strings and then replace the value of `x1` with `x1`.

```
syms a1 a2  t th(t) p(t)
x1 =  a1*sin(th);
x2 = x1 + a2*sin(p);
strrep(char(x2),char(x1),'x1')
```

```
ans =

    'a2*sin(p(t)) + x1'
```

Comment: Sorry but this is rather a meaningless solution. x1 need to be calculated first. I have a lot of equations. Doing them manually will be better than what you've suggested.

Comment: Because x2 depends on x1. Other variables depend on x2 and so on. There are a lot of derivatives involved. You got the point.

Comment: See the alternative approach

Comment: @CroCo This "meaningless solution" answered your question as it was given... if you need a different approach then consider making that approach clear in the question :)

Comment: @Wolfie you probably need to read the question carefully then. This doesn't answer the question. This is exactly like doing it manually. It assumes that I know the term before performing the calculations but that is not the case.

Comment: You didn't state that is the requirement in your question, that's my point! You can't expect people to infer all of your meaning from looking at 5 lines of code, swapping 2 lines seems a simple fix otherwise. Just trying to help you ask a better question to get a better answer

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, as follows:

Declare all of your symbolic variables

```
syms a1 a2 x1 x2 th(t) p(t)
```

Define the equations (in any order, regardless of dependencies)

```
x1 = a1*sin(th);
% other code ...
x2 = a2*sin(p) + x1;
```

Then you can use `subs`

> `subs(s,old,new)` returns a copy of `s` replacing all occurrences of `old` with `new`, and then evaluating `s`.

```
subs(x2, x1, 'x1'); 

>> x1 + a2*sin(p(t))
```

---

Now if we change x1, we can update how it fits into `x2`

```
x1 = a2*sin(p(t));
subs(x2,x1,'x1')
>> x1 + a1*sin(th(t))
```

Comment: btw isn't it what AVK suggested and the OP didn't like?

Comment: Not quite, since AVK didn't declare `x1` and `x2` as variables (hence why I made that line prominent) you cannot define them in any order, as to use `x1` in `x2` it must exist. Setting it up like this is more flexible, and I think it addresses what the asker was having difficulty with. I also tried to be more direct with my example, directly reflecting the asker's own example.

Comment: Although I am not very hopeful that the OP is going to like it. But thanks for clarifiying

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subs` to replace a subexpression with another subexpression. For example,

```
syms a1 a2 t th(t) p(t)
x1 =  a1*sin(th);
x2 = x1 + a2*sin(p)+sin(th)*a1^2+a1*2*sin(th)
result = subs(x2,x1,'x1')
```

gives

> result(t) =
>
> 3*x1 + a2*sin(p(t)) + a1*x1

However, sometimes it doesn't work;

```
x3= a1*2*sin(th/2)*cos(th/2)
result= subs(x3,x1,'x1')
```

gives

> result(t) =
>
> 2*a1*cos(th(t)/2)*sin(th(t)/2)

But `subs(simplify(x3),x1,'x1')` works again

Comment: But this implies that I know the dependency ahead of time. That's not the case.

Comment: You don't need to know `x1` until you replace it. `subs(x2,x1,'x1')` works exactly as `subs(x2,a1*sin(th),'x1')`